# Oracle Online Patching -- How To Exclude Tables in a Custom Schema

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to exclude specific table objects from online patching? I believe the custom schema in which these tables exist is included in online patching. We are running 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine how the Online patching even knows about the custom schema unless it is 'customised' rather than 'custom'. I can see that you may affect custom objects if you  have made referential links to non-custom objects. Can you provide a little more info otherwise it sounds like time to raise a call with Oracle for clarification.

Comment: It's an Oracle release 12. It looks like the consultants set up the custom schema to using online patching.  (There are views named with the # sign at the end for each of the custom objects, etc.)  If I delete those views would that de-couple those objects from the online patching? (I'm a programmer not a DBA so I'm rather out of my depth.)

Answer (score 1):

@Jeff As your database is 12c, you can query `dba_objectes` and check the the oracle_maintained column, e.g. `select OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, STATUS, ORACLE_MAINTAINED from dba_objects where OBJECT_NAME='MyObject';`. If ORACLE_MAINTAINED is set to 'Y', then your object is likely to be affected by patching, if not it will be ignored.

Comment: Our particular database is 11g  Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0.  There is however a column for "edition_name". Can I make the assumption if it's not null that's an equivalent to oracle_maintained = 'Y'?

Comment: No, you can't make that assumption.I don't think you can really tell in 11g if a procedure is oracle internal. All you could do is query the `CREATED` timestamp and and correlate it to the installation date of your database. I assumed 12c according to your comment on the original question.